# Why isn't tangential acceleration just always 0?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, vectors, differentiation, calculus

This is probably a very stupid question but I can't help me.

Tangential acceleration is $\vec{a_t}=\frac{dv}{dt}\frac{\vec{v}}{v}=\frac{\vec{v} \cdot \vec{a}}{v} \frac{\vec{v}}{v}$. Since $\vec{a}$ is the time derivative of $\vec{v}$ they should always be orthogonal to each other, so $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{a}=0$ and therefore always $\vec{a_t}=0$, which is of course wrong. What is wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134249/discussion-on-question-by-quaeram-why-isnt-tangential-acceleration-just-always).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, acceleration can of course easily be parallel to the speed. Drive straight ahead and then speed up. That was an acceleration vector parallel to the velocity vector.

When using the word *tangential*, I can hear that you are specifically referring to **circle motion**.

But it seems that you are isolating your thinking to the special-case of **uniform** circular motion. That is when the speed remains unchanged, such as driving around a roundabout at constant speed. In that very specific scenario you are correct that there is no tangential acceleration component. There is only the perpendicular, centre-directed radial acceleration component (called centripetal acceleration).

But imagine driving around the roundabout and then *speeding up*. You still move in a circular motion, so there is still a radial acceleration component. But you now speed up, meaning you are changing the magnitude of your velocity vector. *Only* a parallel acceleration vector can change the magnitude of the velocity vector. And such parallel acceleration is tangential. So there *must* be a tangential acceleration present if you ever speed up while driving in circles. You are then doind **non-uniform circular motion**.

Answer (score 0):

$\vec{v} \cdot \vec{a}$ generally is not zero.

However,
for an object travelling in a uniform circular path:
$$\vec{R} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(t) \cr \sin(t) \end{bmatrix}$$ $$\frac{\vec{dR}}{dt} = \begin{bmatrix} -\sin(t) \cr \cos(t)  \end{bmatrix}$$ $$\frac{\vec{d^2R}}{dt^2} = \begin{bmatrix} -\cos(t) \cr -\sin(t) \end{bmatrix}$$ $$ \begin{bmatrix} -\sin(t) \cr \cos(t)  \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} -\cos(t) \cr -\sin(t) \end{bmatrix} $$ $$\sin(t)\cos(t)-\sin(t)\cos(t) = 0$$

Comment: this is not correct you should start with $$ \vec R=\left[ \begin {array}{c} \cos \left( s \left( t \right)  \right) 
\\\sin \left( s \left( t \right)  \right) 
\end {array} \right]
$$ with r=1

Comment: Specifically for uniform motion, the dot product is zero

Comment: uniform you mean $\frac{dv}{dt}=0~$ v is the speed $\frac {ds}{dt}$

Comment: Uniform circular motion doesn't require $\frac{dv}{dt} $ = 0. If that were the case, I would have a straight line path.  It requires that |v| to be constant. whilst travelling in a circle. V is velocity.

Comment: The acceleration in uniform circular motion is perpendicular to the velocity. Meaning no work is being done  and it travels at a constant speed.